# How to enumerate OneDrive for Business shared documents for all Office365 enterprise users

Tags: ms-office, sharepoint-2013, preview, office365, office365-apps

How can get a list of all of the files which are currently shared by all of my enterprise's users via OneDrive for Business from my enterprises Office365/SharePoint deployment?

Ideally I would like a CSOM FileCollection.

Currently I think I may need to enumerate all user's personal sites via the Tenant APIs, then connect to and enumerate the content of each of these sites document libraries individually.

Is there an easier way to do this?

How can I get the links that a file has been shared with, if it has been shared?  The CSOM File class doesn't seem to have anything related to links.